# Export array<string> type to csv using PySpark without specifying them one by one?

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, export-to-csv

I've a DataFrame with a lot of columns. Some of these columns are of the type `array<string>`.
I need to export a sample to csv and csv doesn't support array.
Now I'm doing this for every array column (sometimes is miss one or more)

```
df_write = df\
.withColumn('col_a', F.concat_ws(',', 'col_a'))\
.withColumn('col_g', F.concat_ws(',', 'col_g'))\
....
```

Is there a way to use a loop and do this for every array column without specifying them one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the type of each column and do a list comprehension:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType

arr_col = [
    i.name
    for i in df.schema
    if isinstance(i.dataType, ArrayType)
]

df_write = df.select([
    F.concat_ws(',', c)
    if c in arr_col
    else F.col(c)
    for c in df.columns
])
```

Actually, you don't need to use `concat_ws`. You can just cast all columns to string type before writing to CSV, e.g.

```
df_write = df.select([F.col(c).cast('string') for c in df.columns])
```

Comment: "_You can just cast all columns to string type before writing to CSV_" - it depends whether you want the brackets to be printed in the string for arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check the types using `df.dtypes`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

array_cols = [c for c, t in df.dtypes if t == "array<string>"]

df.select(*[
    F.array_join(c, ",").alias(c) if c in array_cols else F.col(c)
    for c in df.columns
])
```